# Azure Storage 1.7 : how to make a simple select that works everytime?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I got a problem with this line, locally and on my azure server :

```
var eq = new EquationEntity().Query().Where(x => x.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm trying to retrieve a row with Key, but it works only 50% of the time (eq is null when it doesn't work). I've check the table, and the row is always there, so this is not the problem.

A few points

- It has nothing to do with the content : rows with same content sometime work or not.
- PartionKey is always the same for all rows.
- Got only 7000 rows on my azure server. Nearly 0 on my local.
- I use Azure SDK 2.2 (so Azure Storage 1.7) (it is an old project)

Please help me doing something that should be simple, but make me loose so much time!

Edit : I just tried this

```
Data.Azure.ServiceContext.CreateQuery<EquationEntity>(TableName).Where(x => x.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
```

It seems to work better. But like, instead of 50%, I got 80%. I need 100%.

Comment: Is there more than one row with the same key?

Comment: I've just check, all row keys seem to be unique. And even if it was the case, it should at least return one row (not a null). no?

Comment: can you try this new EquationEntity().Query().Where(x => x.Key == key).AsTableServiceQuery().FirstOrDefault();

Comment: AsTableServiceQuery() doesn't seem to exist in this context. However, check my edit. With the new code, I can access AsTableServiceQuery(). I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried the AsTableServiceQuery(), but it doesn't seems to help much.

Comment: Is it feasible to build a test app using the latest SDK? There have been many bug fixes to the storage SDK since the 2.2 days...

Comment: Building a test app is totally feasible. The thing is : I didn't develop the app I'm working on, so migrating it would not be easy for me. I already tried with the 2.7, and it was a disaster. Actually, if I was to do this, I would probably just scrap all that Azure thing... I mean : this is a really simple SELECT, it should be super easy, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I found this link :
http://gauravmantri.com/2012/11/17/storage-client-library-2-0-migrating-table-storage-code/

I realized that switching from Azure SDK 2.2 to 2.7 wasn't that hard, and choose this option. It is now working perfectly.